# Multiplying 2 array multidimensional and remove key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array which contain some numbers, and i want to multiplying value of **array which contain key 0** with each other key inside one area array and erase **key 0**.

**Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 5
        )
)
```

Here's the result i want

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 20
        )
)
```

I was already combine it using foreach and for, but it still not working for me, any idea how to do this?

Comment: what you have tried so for? put your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using  `array_map` and `array_slice` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array
foreach ($arr as &$v) {
    $multiplier = $v[0];
    $v = array_map(function($val) use($multiplier){
        return  $multiplier * $val;        
    }, array_slice($v, 1));
}

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 20
        )
)
```

Comment: array_fill is like create a new array and restart each key?

Comment: @JhonnyJr., just creates a new "needed" array

Comment: I know, i just ask the function of array_fill, and by the way your answer is work perfectly, thanks a lot :)

Comment: you're welcome. `array_fill` would be optimal in such case: no need to iterate through each array value doing multiplication. It multiplies just once and replace current array with the needed one

Comment: I see, thanks again for your explanation. Sorry for bothering you, i think it only work like key 0 multiply with key 1, not for all each key. When i try change value from key 2 and more it still look same. Or should i combine it using for loop?

Comment: I think, additional conditions should be added to your question, with respective expected result

Comment: I was already explain it with each other, but i think i'm less specific and i has made a change for array example to make it clear

Comment: You have changed conditions, but it wasn't a big problem to find a new solution. Check my update

Comment: So instead using for loop inside foreach, it'll far more efficient using array_map and the function combination. Because i was try using for loop and doesn't work. Thanks a lot again